# Android eclipse bug?

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

I'm getting errors everywhere that say: cannot be resolved or is not a field to all my R.something.

I'm guessing the R file isn't properly generated and from what I've read it's a problem in the res folder but I cant find it; I deleted the last layout I made but the problem persists.

No layout actually has any errors to be shown (they all build successfully).

Can anyone help me with this bug?

Comment: This commonly happens when you have a resource named incorrectly (names in /res folder should only contain small letters, digits and underscores only)

Comment: I know that and they are named properly.

Comment: Are you targeting a different API, one before the Holo theme came out as it seems to be having a problem finding the Light Holo Theme. If not, try cleaning the project and rebuild

Comment: ops, I did play with the targets trying to solve it. I switched it back and that error is gone but still crashed at R.anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this happening to me with a broken layout. No need to be worry. I am trying my best to giving you the solution

**Solution**

Make sure that anything the **R.** links to is not broken. Fix all errors in your XML files. If anything in the ADKs are broken, R will not regenerate.

If you somehow hit something and created import android.R in your activity, remove it.
Run **Project -> Clean.** This will delete and regenerate R and BuildConfig.

Make sure **Project -> Build** Automatically is ticked. If not, build it manually via **Menu -> Project -> Build Project .**

Wait a few seconds for the errors to disappear.

If it doesn't work, delete everything inside the **/gen/** folder

If it still doesn't work, try right-clicking your **project -> Android Tools -> Fix** Project Properties.

Check your *.properties files (in the root folder of your app folder) and make sure that the links in there are not broken.

Right-click your **project > properties >** Android.

Look at the Project Build Target and Library sections on the right side of the page. Your Build Target should match the target in your AndroidManifest.xml. So if it's set to target 17 in AndroidManifest, make sure that the Target Name is Android 4.2. If your Library has an X under the reference, remove and re-add the library until there's a green tick. This might happen if you've moved a few files and folders around.

**What to do if R doesn't regenerate**

This usually happens when you have a broken xml file.

Check errors inside your XML files, mainly within the **/res/** folder

Common places are **/layout/** and **/values/** especially if you've changed one of them recently

Check **AndroidManifest.xml**, I find that often I change a string, and forget to change the string name from AndroidManifest.xml.

Check that Android SDK Build-tools is installed. **Window->Android SDK Manager->Tools->Android SDK Build-tools**

Make sure when you update the Android SDK Tools, you also update the Android SDK Platform-tools and Android ASK Build-tools. Build fails silently if they don't match.

If you can't find the issue, right click **/gen/ -> Restore from local history... -> tick R.java -> click Restore.** This doesn't solve the problem, but it will clear out the extra errors to make the problem easier to find.

Hope it will help you. :)

Comment: I dont remember when but when the problem first appeared I imported R (thought I removed it with ctr+z). Thanks that was the problem (so pissed)

Answer (score 0):

One (or multiple) xml resources must be broken in your project. Check out "Problems" view in Eclipse (Window - Show view - Problems) and fix all issues there. Then rebuild your project (Project - Clean).

Comment: I get 100 errors all saying that any id/layout reference is broken but that is not true

Comment: There must be one file, which causes this. Normally, it is a file with invalid xml in it. Check out `Error Log` view. If there is a parsing error, you should be able to see something like `"Parser exception for ..."` and name of the broken resource.

Comment: Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in org.eclipse.wst.sse.core

Comment: I've seen your last change to the question. You reference a holo theme with is only available in Android 4.0 and higher. Make sure you reffer to the right verison in AndroidManifest.xml `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />`

Comment: but this is in the folders values-v11/14 that were auto generated and I never changed them. It's been working so far until... I don't know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, just restarting Eclipse can fix the problems.
Some steps you can try:

- Right click project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties
- Right click project -> Refresh
- Right click project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Check everything that's unchecked in 'Order and Export'
- Project -> Clean...
- Restart Eclipse

Might solve your problems!

EDIT: Also make sure there are **no caps** in your XML files.

Comment: all xml resources and layout are ok the problem can only be eclipse. I tried what you said but didnt work. PS:I edited my post